# USB CDC: STM32F103RBT6 Cant get USB Device to show up

Tags: embedded, stm32, cubemx

I got an Olimexino-STM32 with an STM32F103RBT6. I used STM32 Workbench 2.6 on Windows 10 x64 and STMCubeXM 4.27.0.

I choosed in CubeMX

- STM32F103RBT6
- RCC HSE
- USB
- USB Device Communication Device Class
- Debug Line: JTAG 4 pin
- Fix clock speeds
- Add LED1 on PA5 as GPIO Out
- Add LED2 on PA1 as GPIO Out
- Toolchain SW4STM
- Stack size

In main.c in the while loop

```
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(500);
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(500);

        uint8_t HiMsg[] = "hello\r\n";
        CDC_Transmit_FS(HiMsg, strlen(HiMsg));
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

in usb_cdc_if.c

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
    if (Buf[0]=='1')
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

Generate, compile and flash to Board. I can see the LED blinking in the main loop. The speed seems also correct but i just cant get a device registered on windows. I can flash the board with an example hex file from the  distributor with the bootloader active. There i can get the COM port registered. So i can see the USB Port is ok but somehow the generated code doesnt register the COM port.

Any Ideas?

https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/STM32/OLIMEXINO-STM32/

Here is the test1.ioc file

```
#MicroXplorer Configuration settings - do not modify
File.Version=6
KeepUserPlacement=false
Mcu.Family=STM32F1
Mcu.IP0=NVIC
Mcu.IP1=RCC
Mcu.IP2=SYS
Mcu.IP3=USB
Mcu.IP4=USB_DEVICE
Mcu.IPNb=5
Mcu.Name=STM32F103R(8-B)Tx
Mcu.Package=LQFP64
Mcu.Pin0=PD0-OSC_IN
Mcu.Pin1=PD1-OSC_OUT
Mcu.Pin2=PA5
Mcu.Pin3=PA11
Mcu.Pin4=PA12
Mcu.Pin5=VP_SYS_VS_ND
Mcu.Pin6=VP_SYS_VS_Systick
Mcu.Pin7=VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS
Mcu.PinsNb=8
Mcu.ThirdPartyNb=0
Mcu.UserConstants=
Mcu.UserName=STM32F103RBTx
MxCube.Version=4.27.0
MxDb.Version=DB.4.0.270
NVIC.BusFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.DebugMonitor_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.HardFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.MemoryManagement_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.NonMaskableInt_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.PendSV_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.PriorityGroup=NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4
NVIC.SVCall_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.SysTick_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.USB_LP_CAN1_RX0_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.UsageFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false
PA11.Mode=Device
PA11.Signal=USB_DM
PA12.Mode=Device
PA12.Signal=USB_DP
PA5.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PA5.GPIO_Label=LED1
PA5.Locked=true
PA5.Signal=GPIO_Output
PCC.Checker=false
PCC.Line=STM32F103
PCC.MCU=STM32F103R(8-B)Tx
PCC.PartNumber=STM32F103RBTx
PCC.Seq0=0
PCC.Series=STM32F1
PCC.Temperature=25
PCC.Vdd=3.3
PD0-OSC_IN.Mode=HSE-External-Oscillator
PD0-OSC_IN.Signal=RCC_OSC_IN
PD1-OSC_OUT.Mode=HSE-External-Oscillator
PD1-OSC_OUT.Signal=RCC_OSC_OUT
PinOutPanel.RotationAngle=0
RCC.ADCFreqValue=36000000
RCC.AHBFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.APB1CLKDivider=RCC_HCLK_DIV2
RCC.APB1Freq_Value=36000000
RCC.APB1TimFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.APB2Freq_Value=72000000
RCC.APB2TimFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.FCLKCortexFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.FamilyName=M
RCC.HCLKFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.IPParameters=ADCFreqValue,AHBFreq_Value,APB1CLKDivider,APB1Freq_Value,APB1TimFreq_Value,APB2Freq_Value,APB2TimFreq_Value,FCLKCortexFreq_Value,FamilyName,HCLKFreq_Value,MCOFreq_Value,PLLCLKFreq_Value,PLLMCOFreq_Value,PLLMUL,SYSCLKFreq_VALUE,SYSCLKSource,TimSysFreq_Value,USBFreq_Value,USBPrescaler,VCOOutput2Freq_Value
RCC.MCOFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.PLLCLKFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.PLLMCOFreq_Value=36000000
RCC.PLLMUL=RCC_PLL_MUL9
RCC.SYSCLKFreq_VALUE=72000000
RCC.SYSCLKSource=RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK
RCC.TimSysFreq_Value=72000000
RCC.USBFreq_Value=48000000
RCC.USBPrescaler=RCC_USBCLKSOURCE_PLL_DIV1_5
RCC.VCOOutput2Freq_Value=8000000
USB_DEVICE.CLASS_NAME_FS=CDC
USB_DEVICE.IPParameters=VirtualMode,VirtualModeFS,CLASS_NAME_FS
USB_DEVICE.VirtualMode=Cdc
USB_DEVICE.VirtualModeFS=Cdc_FS
VP_SYS_VS_ND.Mode=No_Debug
VP_SYS_VS_ND.Signal=SYS_VS_ND
VP_SYS_VS_Systick.Mode=SysTick
VP_SYS_VS_Systick.Signal=SYS_VS_Systick
VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS.Mode=CDC_FS
VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS.Signal=USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS
board=custom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The Olimexino-STM32 has an output to connect and disconnect the USB. I had not configured that output pin.